# iPhone SDK - UIImageView: position of image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a standard `UIImageView` with its *ContentMode* set to `UIContentModeAspectRatioFit`.
I am trying to find out how to get the position of the image relative to either the absolute coordinates or the `UIImageView` origin.

Is this possible? I have seen lots of posts about how it's not possible to set the position, but nothing on whether or not it's possible to **GET** the position.

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out with a bit of a hack.

I used *Trevor Harmon's* image `resizedImageWithContentMode` function to resize the image to the size of the UIImageView. Then I kept the image size and did away with the image (I only need the size, not the image itself). Followed with some simple math, and we have the position of the image in the frame!

```
    CGSize imageInViewSize = [photo resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:imageView.size interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationNone].size;


    CGRect overlayRect = CGRectMake((imageView.frame.size.width - imageInViewSize.width) / 2,
                                        (imageView.frame.size.height - imageInViewSize.height) / 2, 
                                        imageInViewSize.width, 
                                        imageInViewSize.height);

    NSLog(@"Frame of Image inside UIImageView: Left:%f Top:%f Width:%f Height:%f \n", overlayRect.origin.x, overlayRect.origin.y, overlayRect.size.width, overlayRect.size.height);
```

FYI: Trevor Harmon's code is at: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/

Answer (score 8):

I know this has been answered, but I wrote a function to calculate the frame of an image inside an imageView in respect to the imageView.

Edit: forgot the most important ones.

```
+ (CGRect) imagePositionInImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView
{
    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 0.0f;
    float w = 0.0f;
    float h = 0.0f;
    CGFloat ratio = 0.0f;
    CGFloat horizontalRatio = imageView.frame.size.width / imageView.image.size.width;
    CGFloat verticalRatio = imageView.frame.size.height / imageView.image.size.height;

    switch (imageView.contentMode) {
        case UIViewContentModeScaleToFill:
            w = imageView.frame.size.width;
            h = imageView.frame.size.height;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:
            // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
            ratio = MIN(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
            w = imageView.image.size.width*ratio;
            h = imageView.image.size.height*ratio;
            x = (horizontalRatio == ratio ? 0 : ((imageView.frame.size.width - w)/2));
            y = (verticalRatio == ratio ? 0 : ((imageView.frame.size.height - h)/2));
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill:
            // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
            ratio = MAX(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
            w = imageView.image.size.width*ratio;
            h = imageView.image.size.height*ratio;
            x = (horizontalRatio == ratio ? 0 : ((imageView.frame.size.width - w)/2));
            y = (verticalRatio == ratio ? 0 : ((imageView.frame.size.height - h)/2));
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeCenter:
            // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
            w = imageView.image.size.width;
            h = imageView.image.size.height;
            x = (imageView.frame.size.width - w)/2;
            y = (imageView.frame.size.height - h)/2;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeTop:
            w = imageView.image.size.width;
            h = imageView.image.size.height;
            x = (imageView.frame.size.width - w)/2;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeBottom:
            w = imageView.image.size.width;
            h = imageView.image.size.height;
            y = (imageView.frame.size.height - h);
            x = (imageView.frame.size.width - w)/2;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeLeft:
            w = imageView.image.size.width;
            h = imageView.image.size.height;
            y = (imageView.frame.size.height - h)/2;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeRight:
            w = imageView.image.size.width;
            h = imageView.image.size.height;
            y = (imageView.frame.size.height - h)/2;
            x = (imageView.frame.size.width - w);
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeTopLeft:
            w = imageView.image.size.width;
            h = imageView.image.size.height;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeTopRight:
            w = imageView.image.size.width;
            h = imageView.image.size.height;
            x = (imageView.frame.size.width - w);
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeBottomLeft:
            w = imageView.image.size.width;
            h = imageView.image.size.height;
            y = (imageView.frame.size.height - h);
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeBottomRight:
            w = imageView.image.size.width;
            h = imageView.image.size.height;
            y = (imageView.frame.size.height - h);
            x = (imageView.frame.size.width - w);
        default:
            break;
    }
    return CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
}
```

Comment: this is the most efficient way to find x and y position i found. loved it..!

Answer (score 3):

The center of the image is equal to the center of the view. Everything else you have to calculate yourself based on the aspect ratios of image and view.

Comment: HI can u please tell me , what is "photo".. i  mean the type  in this line " CGSize imageInViewSize = [photo resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:imageView.size interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationNone].size;"  answered  by "Brett"  Thanks in Advance  @Ole Begemann

Comment: @Babul: Why don't you put your comment where it belongs (i.e., under Brett's answer)?

Comment: He is not watching stack over flow now.. He saw the stackover flow 2 days ago @Ole Begemann

Answer (score 0):

you can not do that. The UIImageView, as it implies, shows the image, nothing else.

but more generally, why would you like to add a padding inside a UIImageView ? Wouldn't it be simpler to position the frame as you need ?

Comment: I am trying to add an overlay to the UIImageView, but I only want to overlay to appear where the actual image is. When the contentMode is set to AspectFit, I need the actual position of the image.